# How to adjust the height of verbatimTextOutput within box?

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard

I am not able to fit the output within the box size.

Please refer below image for clear understanding.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzQpf.png)

Here is the code

tabPanel("Detailed Cost Breakup", icon = icon("clipboard-list"),

```
  fluidRow( 
    box(
     title = "Cost Break-up",

     width = 4,

     height = "600px",

     solidHeader = F,

     status = "info",

     collapsible = T,

     collapsed = F,

      tags$strong(verbatimTextOutput(ns("weight1"))),

      tags$strong(verbatimTextOutput(ns("material1"))),

      tags$strong(verbatimTextOutput(ns("process1"))),

      tags$strong(verbatimTextOutput(ns("sga1"))),

      tags$strong(verbatimTextOutput(ns("icc1")))...))
```

Comment: does not work with `height = "100%"` ?

Comment: Thank you !! It worked..

Comment: What worked? You did not showed...